# Overlapping texts

Tags: support, feature-request

I notice that increasingly when I look at an SE entry comments are overwritten by extraneous text and further that in at least one case the bottom of a question overlaps the answer. How can the various elements be separated and not overlap each other?

Comment: I haven't seen overlapping, but more and more frequently various elements on a page are moved around, colors change, other unfamiliar formatting causes me to have to look for something that used to be predictable.  If you can put up a scan of some examples, what you describe should be looked at by someone among the "powers".  It's not anything that can be controlled just on our little island.

Comment: I'd suggest posting some pictures of what you're talking about, including stating the browser you're using where/when this occurs. Does changing to a different browser fix things? Say, to Firefox or Chrome from IE? Do you have any extensions running within the browser that might cause the problem?

Comment: @Werner and barbarabeeton. I'm hopelessly out of date and my grandchildren can't see me to help. How do I scan/take pictures of the SE output I am seeing in my Firefox (and Chrome) browser running under Ubuntu, unchanged for several years? I have never yet found a way to post such graphics to SE. I can live with how it is so no great deal, just wondering if anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Perhaps [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html) helps? Are you running any extensions within Chrome/Firefox that you know of?